# When using DateTime.ParseExact, how do you specify what the timezone is of the given date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

Given the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(timeStamp, "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How do you specify that the given time is UTC?  Right now the result is giving it my current timezone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add [`DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=net-7.0), since it's not specified in the format.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(timeStamp, "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the timezone offset at the end of the parse string like so

`DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01 12:00:00-5:00")`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: Is different for ParseExact, you don´t know the format of it

Answer (score 1):

Following agent-j's answer, you can add the DateTimeStyles to DateTime.Parse(...)

```
date= "Wed, 16 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT";` // from javascript.getUTCString()

DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal));
```